# Trouble with writing separate JSON entries Python

Tags: python, json, file-io

Hopefully someone can tell me why this is happening. What I have here are three movies and I am trying to systematically get each and everyone of the movie's JSON data and print them into a separate file called data_fetch.txt. The site that I'm using is omdbapi.com. I am able to get all movies' JSON successfully, but for some weird reason, when it is being written, it is being written all as one entry. Thus, when I open the file that I just wrote and do a count of the entries, the counter only spits out 1 entry when there should've been 3 separate entries. So there should've been 3 JSON for 3 movie titles. The reason why I would like to separate each JSON into its own entry is because I would like to fetch its "genre" that is in the JSON. Also, I'm not sure if this is connected to the problem, but when I print each JSON entry to the python interpreter I get this error ValueError: Extra data:

Here's the code:

```
import urllib2, time, csv, json, re
def get_url(title):
    base_url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t='
    title_url = str(title)
    total_url = base_url + title_url
    return total_url

def get_json():
    file = open('data_fetch.txt', 'wb')
    lst = [['2010', 'Colin Firth', "The King's Speech "], ['2009', 'Jeff Bridges', 'Crazy Heart '], ['2008', 'Sean Penn', 'Milk ']]
    for item in lst:
        movie = item[2].strip()
        if ' ' in movie:
            title = movie.replace(' ', '%20')
        else:
            title = movie

        reply = urllib2.urlopen(get_url(title))
        html_doc = reply.read()
        file.write(html_doc)
        print html_doc

        time.sleep(5)
    file.close()
def counter():
    file = open('data_fetch.txt', 'rU')
    counter = 0 
    for entry in file: 
        counter+=1
    return counter
    file.close()

print counter() # this only prints 1

def json_data():
    file = open('data_fetch.txt', 'rU')
    for entry in file: 
        decoded = json.loads(entry)
        print decoded
    file.close()
jsond_data() #ValueError: Extra data:
```

Hopefully someone can help me out, I've been fiddling with this for the past 3 hours. I'm using Python 2.7.

Update: Here's the content for my file: data_fetch.txt:

{"Title":"The King's Speech","Year":"2010","Rated":"R","Released":"25 Dec 2010","Runtime":"118 min","Genre":"Biography, Drama, History","Director":"Tom Hooper","Writer":"David Seidler (screenplay)","Actors":"Colin Firth, Helena Bonham Carter, Derek Jacobi, Robert Portal","Plot":"The story of King George VI of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, his impromptu ascension to the throne and the speech therapist who helped the unsure monarch become worthy of it.","Language":"English","Country":"UK, USA, Australia","Awards":"Won 4 Oscars. Another 104 wins & 136 nominations.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzU5MjEwMTg2Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzM3MTYxNA@@._V1_SX300.jpg","Metascore":"88","imdbRating":"8.1","imdbVotes":"355,037","imdbID":"tt1504320","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}{"Title":"Crazy Heart","Year":"2009","Rated":"R","Released":"05 Feb 2010","Runtime":"112 min","Genre":"Drama, Music, Romance","Director":"Scott Cooper","Writer":"Scott Cooper, Thomas Cobb (novel)","Actors":"Jeff Bridges, James Keane, Anna Felix, Paul Herman","Plot":"A faded country music musician is forced to reassess his dysfunctional life during a doomed romance that also inspires him.","Language":"English, Spanish","Country":"USA","Awards":"Won 2 Oscars. Another 35 wins & 18 nominations.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU0NDc5NjgzNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzc0NDIzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg","Metascore":"83","imdbRating":"7.3","imdbVotes":"55,547","imdbID":"tt1263670","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}{"Title":"Milk","Year":"2008","Rated":"R","Released":"30 Jan 2009","Runtime":"128 min","Genre":"Biography, Drama, History","Director":"Gus Van Sant","Writer":"Dustin Lance Black","Actors":"Sean Penn, Emile Hirsch, Josh Brolin, Diego Luna","Plot":"The story of Harvey Milk, and his struggles as an American gay activist who fought for gay rights and became California's first openly gay elected official.","Language":"English","Country":"USA","Awards":"Won 2 Oscars. Another 62 wins & 95 nominations.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI2OTM5NjUzMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzY1MTM5MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg","Metascore":"84","imdbRating":"7.7","imdbVotes":"114,699","imdbID":"tt1013753","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}

Comment: Could you post the contents of the 'data_fetch.txt' file?

Comment: 'file' is a built-in function and data type -- it would be good to change it in the above to 'f' or 'data_file' or something...

Comment: I just changed file to data_file and the same thing happens. I'm only printing one entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a new line at the end of each line, otherwise all gets written in the same line:

```
file.write(html_doc + '\n')
```

By the way a few improvements to your code:

```
import urllib2, time, csv, json, re

def get_url(title):
    base_url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t='
    title = title.strip().replace(' ', '%20')
    return base_url + title


def get_json(lst, filename):
    data = []
    for year, actors, title in lst:
        data.append(urllib2.urlopen(get_url(title)).read())
        time.sleep(5)

    # save data to file
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)


def json_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f: 
        return json.load(f)


def counter(filename):
    return len(json_data(filename))

lst = [['2010', 'Colin Firth', "The King's Speech "], ['2009', 'Jeff Bridges', 'Crazy Heart '], ['2008', 'Sean Penn', 'Milk ']]
filename = 'data_fetch.txt'
get_json(lst, filename)
print counter(filename)
print json_data(filename)
```

Comment: While this solves the number of entries, I'm not sure if this is the answer, because whenever I print JSON entries, I get this in the interpreter: {u'Response': u'False', u'Error': u'Incorrect IMDb ID'}, Would this be because I'm adding a newline to what's being written?

Comment: @jasonadams, I don't think so, your code runs ok on my end. Have you made any other modification?

Comment: hmmm that's quite strange. so on your end, you can print out the JSON entries correctly?

Comment: Yep, the only thing that is changing is how you write to the file, the printing is the same in your code and in my code.

Comment: ok thanks, yeah, my code is not the most efficient, but when I added def get_json2():
    f = open('data_fetch.txt', 'rU')
    for l in f:
        decoded = json.loads(l)
        print decoded
get_json2()                   to your code, it spits out this message: ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 818 - line 1 column 2255 (char 817 - 2254), so I'm starting to think maybe it's my computer?

Comment: @jasonadams, glad to help, did you see the last version? I added your json_data function

Comment: yes i did, thanks a lot for taking the time in rewriting my code